# Compare password with Hashed + Salt generated by Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, passwords

I'm trying to authenticate users in Mysql database generated by Symfony 2. In `Security.yml` I have this :

```
security:
    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512
```

In User Table there is 2 fields : `Salt` and `Password`.

All passwords are like that :

```
YqkYUe0pV/TAw12aG2UcBax0hnJNeHez/S0uBGbnDDBxWD2Yeetqm4DfMn/8WKILIeRpM7ncTJ9coYOiNPGeOA==
```

I'm working on a webservice to authenticate users using PHP. I don't which functions do I have to use to compare plain password with the encrypted ones?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-controls-authorization)?

Comment: Exactly when do you compare plain passwords with encrypted? I am guessing you are being sent encrypted passwords via the web service in the first place? If a password is authenticated from a web service side, the password sent to the web service shouldn't matter. Is this the case? or you are comparing in plain PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the class that handles the sha512 encryption in Symfony2

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php

Comment: Thank you very much that's what i was searching for :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the password encoder factory from the container.

You can do so like this :

```
$factory = $container->get('security.encoder_factory'); //$container refers to your container, it can be also $this->container
$user = new Your\Bundle\Entity\User();

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($nonEncodedPassword, $user->getSalt());
```

This should be enough. Of course you can set "by hand" the second `encodePassword` parameter as its the salt used to encode all paswords. It's usually defined in your user implementation class, that's why we give here an entity instancied object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i'm not using Symfony framework but PHP directly. Is possible to do the same thing ?

Comment: Then you have to take really care of what tags you are using when asking something in Stackoverflow : if this has nothing to deal with Symfony2, then, WHY is there the Symfony2 tag in the question, as it is not symfony2 related DIRECTLY? :)

Comment: I'm working on a database created and managed by Symfony2 website. But my script (to authentificate users) is not a part of the Symfony site.

Comment: That's exactly what I understood.